# Able to use SSH w/ python and Linux but not able to use SSH w/ python and Sonicwall

Tags: python, firewall, paramiko

I am working on using Paramiko in python to Automate various SSH tasks. One thing I would like to do is Run some commands on a sonicwall. I have some code that will allow me to run commands on an Ubunutu VM but the same code will not work with a Sonicwall. The only thing changing is the variables (username, password, ip address, etc) Below is the code and errors that I am receiving. Could anyone help enlighten me on why this is not working as expected?

````
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
host = '192.168.16.75'
port, user, password = 22, 'scott', 'scott'
ssh.connect(host, port,  user, password)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("ls -l")

for line in stdout.readlines():
    print(line)

ssh.close()

#ABOVE WORKS W/ UBUNTU

#BELOW DOES NOT WORK WITH SONICWALL

import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
host = '192.168.16.63'
port, user, password = 22, 'admin', 'password'
ssh.connect(host, port,  user, password)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("show arp")

for line in stdout.readlines():
    print(line)

#BELOW IS THE ERRORS PYTHON THROWS

C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:/Users/scott/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches/scratch_6.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/scott/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches/scratch_6.py", line 8, in <module>
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("show arp")
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 514, in exec_command
    chan.exec_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 72, in _check
    return func(self, *args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 257, in exec_command
    self._wait_for_event()
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 1226, in _wait_for_event
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2055, in run
    ptype, m = self.packetizer.read_message()
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 459, in read_message
    header = self.read_all(self.__block_size_in, check_rekey=True)
  File "C:\Users\scott\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 303, in read_all
    raise EOFError()
EOFError

Process finished with exit code 1 ```
````

Comment: Hope the answer helped, if it did, don't hesitate to mark the answer as correct. Welcome to Stackoverflow :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You SSH server probably doesn't allow `exec_command()`.

You can verify this by executing the following ssh command:

```
ssh user@host c i eth i
```

If you get a

> "Connection to x.x.x. closed by remote host."

then it is not supported.

You should instead start an interactive shell in paramiko:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect('credentials here')
chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
chan.send('command here\n')
output = chan.recv()
```

Comment: I will give this a try ASAP. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help! If you have other questions just let me know :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue, when I try what is mentioned above, I get 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sonic.py", line 12, in <module>
    ssh.connect(hostname='192.168.138.1',username='admin',password='password')
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 416, in connect
    self, server_hostkey_name, server_key
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 824, in missing_host_key
    "Server {!r} not found in known_hosts".format(hostname)
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Server '192.168.138.1' not found in known_hosts

Comment: Try this right after the first line: ssh.load_system_host_keys() ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())